# nginx taking too long to respond

Tags: nginx, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

I have an nginx used mainly as a reverse proxy for a couple of upstream services. This nginx has a simple endpoint used for health checks:

```
    location /ping { return 200 '{"ping":"successful"}'; }
```

The problem I'm having is that this ping takes too long to be responded:

```
    $ cat /proc/loadavg; date ; httpstat localhost/ping?foo=bar
    2.93 1.98 1.94 8/433 16725
    Thu Jul 15 15:25:08 UTC 2021
    Connected to 127.0.0.1:80 from 127.0.0.1:42946

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2021 15:26:24 GMT
    X-Request-ID: b8d276b0b3828113cfee3bf2daa01293

      DNS Lookup   TCP Connection   Server Processing   Content Transfer
    [     4ms    |       0ms      |      76032ms      |        0ms       ]
                 |                |                   |                  |
        namelookup:4ms            |                   |                  |
                            connect:4ms               |                  |
                                          starttransfer:76036ms          |
                                                                     total:76036ms
```

That ^ is telling me that the average load is low at the time of the request (2.93 the 1m average load for an 8-core server is ok)

Curl/httpstat initiated the request at 15:25:08 and response was obtained 15:26:24.
Connection was stablished fast, request sent, then it took 76s for the server to respond.

If I look at the access log for this ping I see "req_time":"0.000" (this is the $request_time variable).

```
  {"t":"2021-07-15T15:26:24+00:00","id":"b8d276b0b3828113cfee3bf2daa01293","cid":"18581172","pid":"13631","host":"localhost","req":"GET /ping?foo=bar HTTP/1.1","scheme":"","status":"200","req_time":"0.000","body_sent":"21","bytes_sent":"373","content_length":"","request_length":"85","stats":"","upstream":{"status":"","sent":"","received":"","addr":"","conn_time":"","resp_time":""},"client":{"id":"#","agent":"curl/7.58.0","addr":",127.0.0.1:42946"},"limit_status":{"conn":"","req":""}}
```

This is the access log format in case anybody wonders what are the rest of the values:

```
  log_format main escape=json '{"t":"$time_iso8601","id":"$ring_request_id","cid":"$connection","pid":"$pid","host":"$http_host","req":"$request","scheme":"$http_x_forwarded_proto","status":"$status","req_time":"$request_time","body_sent":"$body_bytes_sent","bytes_sent":"$bytes_sent","content_length":"$content_length","request_length":"$request_length","stats":"$location_tag","upstream":{"status":"$upstream_status","sent":"$upstream_bytes_sent","received":"$upstream_bytes_received","addr":"$upstream_addr","conn_time":"$upstream_connect_time","resp_time":"$upstream_response_time"},"client":{"id":"$http_x_auth_appid$http_x_ringdevicetype#$remote_user$http_x_auth_userid","agent":"$http_user_agent","addr":"$http_x_forwarded_for,$remote_addr:$remote_port"},"limit_status":{"conn":"$limit_conn_status","req":"$limit_req_status"}}';
```

My question is: where could nginx have spent these 76s if the request just took 0s to be processed and responded?

Something special to mention is that the server is timing out a lof of connections with the upstreams at that moment as well: we see a lot of `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream` and `upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream`.

So, these two are related, what I can't see is why upstream timeouts would lead to a /ping taking 76s to be attended and responded when both cpu and load are low/acceptable.

Any idea?

Comment: did you find out what was causing it?

Comment: Kind of ... we had a huge shared dictionary (~10G) used as a cache where we were storing big JSON strings with a TTL of ~1d. We reduced the size of the items in the shared dict (from ~10k  to a few hundred bytes) and the problem stopped. Our guess is that there was some kind of "garbage" collection on the shared dict expired items or some sort of nginx maintenance on that shared dict that took too much to complete and blocked the worker. We could never find what was really happening, we just found that reducing the item size fixed the problem